# Optaplanner: how to resize NurseRosteringPanel column?

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

how can I change the column width of the NurseRosteringPanel?
My panel looks like this and I want to resize it.
Thanks

Gian

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Swing layout for that example is clunky, but for what it's worth, it is in this java code: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/swingui/NurseRosteringPanel.java#L48

Comment: Thanks for the reply Geoffrey.

I updated the image before and after Solve. As you can see the spots are always in the same columns. I think it depends on the parallegroup component. My goal is to get a layout with only one column; I think it's only possible by separating the header from the grid.

Comment: Yes, good idea. The UI of this example was written in 2011, with a focus on productivity and being "good enough" to demonstrate the power of OptaPlanner underneath. The non-UI code is held to much, much higher standards.